# How to add user name to reservation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have created a Reservation resource. I implemented Devise so when you want to create a new reservation you have to login or create an account. What I want is that when a reservation is created, the user name of the current user is assigned to it so then I can filter reservations by username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an association, check it out here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

On your `reservations` table, you can add a reference to the User table via `user_id`, and then have a `belongs_to :user`

Then you can show the username by doing `reservation.user.name` wherever you need.

To add the reference, run the following: `rails g migration AddUserToReservations user:references`

Which will generate the following:

```rb
class AddUserToReservations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :reservations, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

and run your migrations `rails db:migrate`

Then, to assign the user to the reservation you should add a line like this in the `create` action of your `reservations_controller.rb`:

```
if @reservation.save
  @reservation.user = current_user
```